# C++ templates and overloading the subscript operator

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

> I am trying to overload the subscript operator in order to use it to
>   fill a template that is used in a map class.

**This is the template structure**

```
  template<typename K, typename V>
    struct Node
    {
        V       Value;
        K       Key;
    };
```

It is used in this class

**Map Class**

```
template<typename K, typename V>
class myMap
{
public:
    myMap();
    ~myMap();

    V& operator[] (const K Key);

private:
    const int       mInitalNumNodes = 10;   //Start length of the map
    int             mNumOfNodes;            //Count of the number of Nodes in the map
    int             mCurrentPostion;
    Node<K,V>       mNodeList[10];
};
```

I want to overload the subscript operator so that I can put a Key and a Value in to the mNodeList with this function call.

**Class and Operator Call**

```
myMap<char, int> x;
x[1] = 2;
```

How ever I keep getting errors on my overload implementation could you point me in the right direction.

**Operator Overload**

```
template<typename K, typename V>
inline V& myMap<K, V>::operator[](const K Key)
{
    // TODO: insert return statement here
    Node<K, V> newNode;
    newNode.Key = Key;

    mNodeList[mCurrentPostion] = newNode;
    mCurrentPostion++;
    return mNodeList[&mCurrentPostion-1];
}
```

**Errors:**

illegal index not allowed

initializing cannot convert from initializer to Node

Comment: `Node<K, V> newNode = {newNode.Key = Key,};` Ehrm ... What?

Comment: This question is not about the subscript operator, but about a problem regarding the initialization of a struct. If you edit the title accordingly and reduce the problem, you might get better answers. (i.e. the problem pointed out by @SimonKraemer should also be a problem in another context.)

Comment: Yeah I fixed that, problem its still the subscript operator not working

Answer (score 1):

Your return is wrong. You most probably want

```
return mNodeList[mCurrentPostion - 1].Value;
```

instead of

```
return mNodeList[&mCurrentPostion-1];
```

**MCVE:**

```
template<typename K, typename V>
struct Node
{
    K       Key;
    V       Value;
};

template<typename K, typename V>
class myMap
{
public:
    myMap()
        :mCurrentPostion(0)
        ,mNumOfNodes(0)
    {}
    ~myMap() {}

    V& operator[] (const K Key);

private:
    const int       mInitalNumNodes = 10;   //Start length of the map
    int             mNumOfNodes;            //Count of the number of Nodes in the map
    int             mCurrentPostion;
    Node<K, V>       mNodeList[10];
};


template<typename K, typename V>
inline V& myMap<K, V>::operator[](const K Key)
{
    // TODO: insert return statement here if Key already exists
    Node<K, V> newNode;
    newNode.Key = Key;
    mNodeList[mCurrentPostion] = newNode;
    mCurrentPostion++;
    return mNodeList[mCurrentPostion - 1].Value;
}

int main()
{
    myMap<char, int> x;
    x[1] = 2;
}
```

Comment: I have tried that already I get cannot convert from Node<K,V> to int&, but also I want to return that array position as that is where the Node, that I want to assign the value you to will be located

Comment: Maybe you should update you question and describe what you are trying to achieve. If possible with an example. _"I get cannot convert from Node<K,V> to int&"_ If `V ` is of type `int` it will work. I'll update my answer to an MVCE